# What is the story of the Rape of Hera?

Tags: greek, hera

A while ago, I read something along this phrase: could be the same (filler name) that raped Hera. I do not know where I read this and have not been able to find it again. The only lead I got was with Zeus. Not what I'm looking for. Who raped Hera and what is the story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Porphyrion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyrion), the "greatest of the Giants" according to Apollodorus, attempted to rape Hera during the [Gigantomachy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giants_(Greek_mythology)#The_Gigantomachy):

> But in the battle Porphyrion attacked Hercules and Hera. Nevertheless Zeus inspired him with lust for Hera, and when he tore her robes and would have forced her, she called for help, and Zeus smote him with a thunderbolt, and Hercules shot him dead with an arrow.
>
> <sub>Source: Source: [Apollod. 1.6.2](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0548.tlg001.perseus-eng1:1.6.2)</sub>

The Hellenistic poet [Euphorion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorion_of_Chalcis) also tells a tale of a giant raping Hera. This time, though, the culprit is Eurymedon, a relatively unknown king of giants mentioned in Book 7 of the *Odyssey*. This story could possibly be a retelling of the Porphyrion tale, or even an attempt by Euphorion to flesh out Homer's story.